# Indexing polymorphic "this" type using filtered keyof type

Tags: typescript

Any ideas on why the following code doesn't seem to compile using ts version 4.2.3:

```js
type NumbersKeys<T extends BaseClass> = keyof {
    // Keys where key is a string and value of key is a number
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends number ? (K extends string ? K : never) : never]: T[K]
};

class BaseClass {
    printNumberKey(prop: NumbersKeys<this>){
        console.log(prop)
    }
    // Why doesnt this work?
    printNumberValuePlusOne(prop: NumbersKeys<this>) {
        console.log(this[prop] + 1)
    }
    // Or this?
    getNumber<T extends NumbersKeys<this>, K extends this[T]>(prop: T) {
        return this[prop]; 
    }
    // But this does?
    getProperty<T extends keyof this>(prop: T): this[T] {
        return this[prop]; 
    }
}

class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
    stringProp: string = '';
    numberProp: number = 0;
    1: number;
}

let instance = new DerivedClass();

instance.printNumberKey('numberProp');
instance.printNumberValuePlusOne('numberProp');
console.log(instance.getNumber('numberProp'));

// Below should error

// instance.printNumberKey('stringProp');
// instance.printNumberValuePlusOne('stringProp');
// console.log(instance.getNumber('stringProp'));

// instance.printNumberKey(1);
// instance.printNumberValuePlusOne(1);
// console.log(instance.getNumber(1));
```

I would expect to be able to use the prop parameter to index into "this", but the compiler cant seem to understand that NumberKeys are keys of "this". Is there a different way to filter keyof values so the compiler understands what I'm attempting to do?

Here's [a link to the typescript playground example of this:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4GcDSEToDwAqAfFALxQDeUAsAFBQNQD0TU2uUA7gBZrQDWOKAEt0UAIZR0wVMIB2AcwlyAJlABu4gDZxoAewBmUQSBFjJcxClR1GUANqYRcqAFEAHjPEBjYHhOGUAQANFIy8gpEALoAXEGOUVAQnhCqYpbIaFAA-GxQcXIQ6mgA3DS0AL72Hl6+-jiBIWGyitF0dN5a4uhiAELdEADCXT2UtoxgLcDwmajsABSTemBxM9ZYOPjA3KJEAJQU43YM3npy6HpaEAB0WnoKi6jLe0dQFa8sUADq3KYqehB0HJgFBtqIuHpUPxsq9JvJplY0AA1bS6AAKOnQAHlCo9lqtERh2Fsduh9mN6McTmcLldbvd5mD0PYlmBEgBqKAARhelIY7z5zFYWNQoNJMMFCggCNmhCSKTSsEJG1weCZRFCTmSwFSKjETPsBCiRDxKyCewpVIYqGlcFQLgNrKiZVeArsn16cBBTKg-0BErsUuAaKekFQoDl2t1YgCRnVpriBD2cQNRstVptwDtDtJLNDzvKdgFAo6IzEABE0MJiipht0xFHFf10EMy+mGNIWgoQ-jmhEyFAAOSDkqvDLWHtm8dZcgABlHgq5BUJC5LtCuIPk0nEcm80HIhU4UErshrdZ68z2C7oW+AO731zhwLWaAWg+nqEng6vN-Od93NxPjK1gojoEAYnA2K4u+hJfj+tCnOclw3HcDy3veNxBi+qDzDBsxwfBdAehAdxHug3B6HAWhqGgTw2LQRGsOhAGPlM2Fvp2ERwQunzMQ+QHYaB6KYjiEC4ZxijcYxUCIbSKEMnxmHSth4nhJJobfoRtC8X+GGsfC7E4PMPI8UxuksQJhJCeBIm4iZ0mych9JoeZD5YYSxl7FpdBAA)

Edit: Edited example to remove issue mentioned in comments below

Comment: You are using a literal string `'never'` instead of `never`.  This is a slight improvement: `type NumbersKeys<T> = { [K in Extract<keyof T, string>]: T[K] extends number ? K : never; }[Extract<keyof T, string>]` but it's still not getting that `this[NumberKeys<this>]` is `number`.

Comment: Thanks! Edited the example. It also still doesn't understand that NumberKeys<this> can be used to index this.

Comment: The code I suggested allows you to access `this[prop]` without problems, but it still has errors because it doesn't understand that `this[prop]` is always `number` https://tsplay.dev/wEV84N

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but your `NumberKeys` type is rather complicated; a simpler implementation is `{[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never}[keyof T] & string`.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) as an implicit [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  Inside the body of `BaseClass`, the `this` type is unspecified; the compiler only knows that `this extends BaseClass`.  It's only when you create an instance that `this` is implicitly specified to be the type of the instance.

And the TypeScript compiler is not particularly adept at reasoning about types that depend on as-yet unspecified generic type parameters; especially when these types are [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like the [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) going on inside `NumbersKeys`.  Generally speaking, the compiler will just *defer* evaluating such types, and it will not be able to verify that any specific value is assignable to them.

It's a design limitation of Typescript.  I'm not sure there's canonical documentation about this, but you can look at issues like [microsoft/TypeScript#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728) or [microsoft/TypeScript#42896](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42896), which have been marked as such because of the inability of the compiler to perform the kind of analysis necessary to verify this.

---

So you will have to work around it.  The easiest way is to just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler what the type of `this[prop]` will be, since it cannot figure it out:

```
printNumberValuePlusOneAssert(prop: NumbersKeys<this>) {
    console.log(this[prop] as unknown as number + 1)
}
```

That shifts the burden of maintaining type safety from the compiler to you, so be careful; you could write `this[prop] as unknown as string` and it would not complain.

---

Another workaround is to give `printNumberValuePlusOne()` a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function) of a type where the compiler can verify that `this[prop]` is a `number`:

```
printNumberValuePlusOne(
    this: Record<NumbersKeys<this>, number>,
    prop: NumbersKeys<this>
) {
    console.log(this[prop] + 1)
}
```

Now there's no error.  If `this` is of type `Record<NumbersKeys<this>, number>`, then indexing into it with a key of type `NumbersKeys<this>` is seen to be `number` by the compiler.  You even get some type safety here, although not where you might expect.  A `this` parameter isn't really checked until you call the method on an instance.  If the instance is of a type that matches the `this` parameter, the call will compile with no error:

```
instance.enforcedLater("numberProp"); // okay
```

Otherwise, you'll get a warning on the instance.  It's hard to show that happening because you already prohibit bad keys sine `prop` is `NumberKeys<this>`.  If you changed it to something like the following though:

```
enforcedLater<K extends keyof this>(
    this: Record<K, number>,
    prop: K
) {
    console.log(this[prop] + 1);
}
```

You can see it the error on the instance itself:

```
instance.enforcedLater("numberProp"); // okay
instance.enforcedLater("stringProp"); // error!
//~~~~~~ <-- Types of property 'stringProp' are incompatible.
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4GcDSEToDwAqAfFALxQDeAsAFBT1QDamUAlgHZQCiAHsKgEMAxsDwBrHAHsAZlAIAaKOn4cA5kQC6ALjnMNUCHwjsAJuijtEKVFAD8UFjvYQAbmgDctAL6Ne-YaISIDJyisqoapq0tEIANgLo5gBCCRAAwvGJlLQMUGAR7MDwyGgAagKxcBAACpXoAPLOAIKJaMAAFPmSYDrF1lg4+MAAFqzoRACU2XS5DEKS7OiSsRAAdLGSqu0jY4xdYPoJUHDsYuySAO6cR5YlNgDUUACMEzkMXtEz9PkcRVZlFSqtTgDWc7TesygO3QOgAShB5qgTHg+mgBrg8NCiIpbtZsRDZvtev8MNgMViCVNqF9ZvNFss1hsttC9qhuvpHi8CR8aATjNJJKghBATAAZATANB4FiGSWmcxBEJY8E03LQuEIwXIzA4kn41UMIkOSnTSH0OlLFbrTbbUboVnsqCciaeGk8nkxTLmAAiaFYbhMGQS5llxjMUBS6HSXtNDHCamqbJ6ShU7FUZCgAHJM67cri0Inuk4SRmAAy5hhPYt3V0emgrYBsRbAATsYUZ5wXKC+iIBoOJdou2gcZSt4WrH6FVGocqVGp1RoQdqZ-OoQtgTMuqAAem3UEkYgEIGHzbHa0nfzus6BC7BmfjafXm-cO73aDZqFou6gAFo--+AMAoDgJIAA-cCIMg8Cvz3JpUFURBjEbJVwGgTMACIH1Udd0MzNhzHORtg1YVR2AEJAVihSQ8gEQQEAgSUbBQyAs3Q1ccMzT4RxbNtzwKS9rGvecQUXdoXhfb930FLjT141Z+UFYUxQlNB2jYkkcK3b8DyPE9RzkhShRFcVGLUrDNIkt9UA-ABCGCoNAqA8D-BgCFQ8wQn2NoQCzcykzw2joA4eYEDACVWAotZaCAA)

Comment: Very helpful and thorough, thank you! Will be going with your second option because of the type safety, and the ts error seems the most helpful